There isn't $(a_n) \in (-\infty, \infty]^\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $ \forall n\geq 1, \Delta a_n >0$ and $(a_1,\infty]= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,a_{n+1}]$
To solve a measure theory exercise, I assumed the following is true (as it seems very reasonable to me)
A neighborhood of infinity (i.e., an interval $(x, \infty]$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$) cannot be written as a countably infinite union of nonempty disjoint intervals of the form $(a ,b ]$ where $a,b \in (\infty, -\infty]$
Equivalently:
There is no $(a_n) \in (-\infty, \infty]^\mathbb{N}$ such that $ \forall n\geq 1, \Delta a_n >0$ and $(a_1,\infty]= \bigcup_ {n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,a_{n+1}]$
The intuition behind this is that whenever we write $(x, \infty]$ as a union of intervals of type $(a,b]$ with $a,b \in (\infty,-\infty]$ , this union must be stationary

You should include your attempt or some intuition at least.

This is false. Without loss of generality, it suffices to show that $(0, 1]$ can be covered with disjoint half-open intervals $(a_{n + 1}, a_n]$: Namely, take $a_n = 1 / 2^n$, so that you get a sequence of intervals $(1/2, 1]$, $(1/4, 1/2]$, $(1/8, 1/4]$, $\ldots$ and therefore
$$
    \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty (a_{n + 1}, a_n] = (0, 1]
$$

sorry, but I don't think you saw infinity written at the upper end of the range.

I did see it. I didn't bother addressing it explicitly because it's covered by the "without loss of generality": After all, if you're trying to cover $(a, \infty]$ you can shift by $-a$, then take $(1, \infty]$ as your first interval to reduce to the problem of covering $(0, 1]$. One could also argue that there exists an order-preserving bijection $(a, \infty] \to (0, 1]$ so that the problems really are equivalent.

Yes but also you made the mistake of writing $(a_{n+1},a_n]$ instead of $(a_n, a_{n+1}]$, wich changes everything. I made the hypotesis of $\Delta a_n>0$ i.e. $(a_n)$ being increasing, not decreasing.

@AlexAhr $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence, so $(a_{n + 1}, a_n]$ is correct. You haven't explained what $\Delta$ is, and before you edited it a few minutes ago your problem read "A neighborhood of infinity (i.e., an interval $(x, \infty]$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$) cannot be written as a countably infinite union of nonempty disjoint intervals of the form $(a, b]$ where $a, b \in (-\infty, \infty]$." This question I answered, and if the second characterization is not actually equivalent, as you claimed, to the first, then that is your fault, not mine.

@AlexAhr In that vein, please revert this last edit. We don't generally allow people to change the meaning of the question once there is an answer. You are of course free to ask a new question.
